# Experience Neptune Gremlin connections problem on calling AWS lambda handlers` callback

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, gremlin, aws-step-functions, amazon-neptune

I am using gremlin@3.3.5 for my Node.js 8.10 application with AWS Lambdas. The process works all fine for a single invocation. Here is my very sample code.

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    dc = new DriverRemoteConnection('wss://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/gremlin');

    const graph = new Graph();
    const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);
    try {
        const result = await g.V().limit(1).count().next();
        dc.close();
        callback(null, { result: result });
    } catch (exception) {
        callback('Error');
        throw error;
    }
}
```

When I run this process for single invocation, it appears to work all fine, but soon as I try to run a batch process of operations (something like 100,000 requests / hr), I am experiencing in CloudWatch log metrics that my connections are not closed successfully. I have tried a number of implementation of this, like callbackWaitForEventLoopEmpty, but that seizes the lambda. When I remove callback (or return similarly), this process works fine with batch operations too. But I do want to return data from this lambda with information that is passed to my step function to trigger another lambda based on that information.

Comment: `return result` works and `callback(null, result)` doesn't?

Comment: No, both don't. They kind of do the same thing I believe.

Comment: But when I neither return or do a callback, the connections get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, I have found out the problem was with how gremlin package was handling the event of closing a connection didn't favor serverless architecture. When triggered driver.close(). When driver is instantiated, it creates instance of client, which inside itself creates instance of connection, which creates instance of websocket using ws library. Now ws.close() event gracefully closes all the events, which doesn't wait for event to be called before my callback is called and that event remains open and leaks. So after explicitly calling dc._client._connection.ws.terminate() on connection instance and then dc.close() closes connection immediately.

Answer (score 1):

`g.V().limit(1).count().next()` is asynchronous.

Try this:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

  try {
      dc = new DriverRemoteConnection('wss://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/gremlin');    
      const graph = new Graph();
      const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);
      const result = await g.V().limit(1).count().next();
      dc.close();
      return result;
  } catch (error) {
      throw error;
  }
}
```

Since your Lambda runtime is Node.js 8.10 you don't need to use `callback`.

Comment: I am using async await too. This problem still exists.

Comment: Even I have logged connection variable, inside there package dc._client._connection.isOpen says true when connection is open then false when connection closed.

Comment: You are not handling promise at least not in the code you showed us.

Comment: Apologies. I just edited my question. This problem still exist.

Comment: you don’t seem to have added ‘async’ in function, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes it is a typo. This has nothing to do with async, It is more of a performance issue on Neptune side. As I side, a normal batch process closes connections successfully. But when processed a heavy operation, (well some 60,000 connections per hour), connections fail to close themselves.